# Leap cannot be applied on compiling test using Java

Tags: java

I've researched for solutions and been working on this ages by getting this far with the exception that I kept getting this two errors during compilation particularly variable might not have been initialized? I've alternate the solutions between two classes but it is similiar errors.

My questions are: how can I solve this errors as below [thank you]. .setIsLeapYear() is called but with no arguments whereas it is defined with one argument in a Leap class.

```
App.java:129: setisLeapYear(int) in Leap cannot be applied to ()
        aLeap.setisLeapYear(); //aLeap.setisLeapYear(anLeapYear);
             ^
App.java:130: setisNotLeapYear(int) in Leap cannot be applied to ()
        aLeap.setisNotLeapYear(); //aLeap.setisNotLeapYear(anNotLeapYear);
```

This line in the code which is preventing me from compiling successfully. I've marked out two lines **[line 129]** and **[line 130]** as below.

```
    **[line 129]** aLeap.setisLeapYear(); //aLeap.setisLeapYear(anLeapYear);
    **[line 130]** aLeap.setisNotLeapYear(); //aLeap.setisNotLeapYear(anNotLeapYear);
    aLeap.sortLeapyear();

    //year=aYear.sortLeapyear();

    oBox.show();
    oBox.print("The " + anLeapYear + " is a leap year."); //leap.anLeapYear //aLeap.anLeapYear //aLeap.isLeapYear
    //"The " + year + " is a leap year.")
    //"The " + year + " is a leap year: " + isLeapYear);
    //System.out.println("This is a leap year!" + isLeapYear);

    oBox.print("The " + anNotLeapYear + " is not a leap year.");
```

I'm also including two full set of classes for your convenience App class and Leap class separately underneath.

**class App** EDITED.

```
import javabook.*;

class App
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    App thisProgram = new App();   



}   
    //outside a main class
    public App()
    {

        //contsructor
        //set variables
        //int aYear = 2000; //year
        int aYear = 2000; EDITED.
        int anLeapYear;
        int anNotLeapYear;

        //declare objects
        MainWindow mWindow;
        Leap aLeap;
        InputBox iBox;
        OutputBox oBox;

        //create objects                
        mWindow = new MainWindow();     
        aLeap = new Leap();
        iBox = new InputBox(mWindow);   
        oBox = new OutputBox(mWindow);  

        mWindow.show();

        //get input of base and height
        aYear = iBox.getInteger("Enter a year: "); //aYear

        int year = aLeap.getisLeapYear();//

        boolean value = true; 
        if (value == true)


        aLeap.setisLeapYear(); //aLeap.setisLeapYear(anLeapYear);
        aLeap.setisNotLeapYear(); //aLeap.setisNotLeapYear(anNotLeapYear);
        aLeap.sortLeapyear();

        //year=aYear.sortLeapyear();

        oBox.show();
        oBox.print("The " + anLeapYear + " is a leap year."); 
        oBox.print("The " + anNotLeapYear + " is not a leap year."); 
        //the end.
    }
}.
```

**class Leap**

```
class Leap
{
    //public static void main(String args[])

    //data
    //private constants
    final int year; 

    //private variables
    private int isLeapYear;
    private int isNotLeapYear;

    //constructors //Leapyear
    public Leap()
    {
        //this.isLeapYear = 0;      
        //this.isNotLeapYear = 0;   
    }
    //methods - behavious
    public void sortLeapyear() 
    {   
        boolean value = true; 
        if (value == true) 

        if (year % 4 == 0) //((year % 4) == 0) 
        {
        if (year % 100 == 0) 
            {
            if (year % 400 != 0)
            {
            }
            if (year % 400 == 0)
            {
            }
    }
        if (year % 100!= 0)
            {
            }
        }
        if (year % 4 != 0)
            {
            }

        //this.isLeapYear = ( ((year % 400) == 0) || ((year % 4) == 0 && (year % 100) != 0)  ); SHOULD BE IN IF STATEMENT ON LEAP YEAR.
        //this.isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0));
        //(year % 400 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 4 == 0); //http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1264964.html
        //http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming_in_Java/Boolean_variables
        //this.isLeapYear = ((year % 4) == 0); //(year % 400 == 0);
        //this.isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);  //found   : boolean   //1 + (int) (Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_SIDES);
        //this.isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0));//1 + (int) (Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_SIDES);
}

        //Set the height and get the height
        public void setisLeapYear(int anLeapYear)
        {
            this.isLeapYear = year;
        }
        //method - Get (accessors) and sets (mutators)
        public int getisLeapYear()
        {
            return(this.isLeapYear);
        }

        public void setisNotLeapYear(int isNotLeapYear)
        {
            this.isNotLeapYear = year;
        }
        //method - Get (accessors) and sets (mutators)
        public int getisNotLeapYear()
        {
            return(this.isNotLeapYear);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? You are not calling the method as it is defined. If you want to call a parameterless method, define such a method.

Comment: I'd say the error is pretty clear, you call `setisLeapYear()` which is not defined

Comment: I've variables in App class and leap class that are not reading in  oBox.print("The " + anLeapYear + " is a leap year."); so its clear that I've set variables incorrectly? .setIsLeapYear() is called but with no arguments whereas it is defined with one argument in a Leap class.

Comment: setisLeapYear() which is not defined and how can I solve this please?

Comment: @stack_user: you define `setisLeapYear(int anLeapYear)`in `Leap` class  put not `setisLeapYear()`

Comment: before coding , learn java, facepalm!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that , you have `setisLeapYear` method take `one argument` and when you call it you send nothing to this method

the solution is :
You can create the `setisLeapYear` which take nothing , like that :

```
 public void setisLeapYear(////nothing here)
 {
...

 }
```

or 
Send `int` to the method which you call it `anLeapYear` , Like that :

```
aLeap.setisLeapYear(///put number here );
```

Comment: aLeap.setisLeapYear(///put number here ); Which number is that? I've int aYear = 2000; on set variables. Is the number 2000 should be placed inside (///put number here )

Comment: this `setisLeapYear` method take a number , so you must send number to it or the compiler will deal with this method as another one but not define

Comment: and the same for `setisNotLeapYear` method , you must send number when you call it

Comment: @stack_user: i don't know which number you need to send , you only know that , but the logic for your code is to send the year ,but which one? , i don't know what your code do , sorry :)

Comment: I've used int aYear = 2000; on set variables and now I've tried int aYear;

Comment: and what is the error now?!

Comment: It is now complied as App.java:137: variable anLeapYear might not have been initialized. oBox.print("The " + anLeapYear + " is a leap year."); What did I miss?

Comment: yes , i can see that  , where is the value of `anLeapYear`?? you need to initialze it

Comment: int anLeapYear; Is that correct?

Comment: yes :) set value to this variable :)

Comment: Can you show me set value to this variable and I'll learn from it.

Comment: exactly like you did in : `int aYear = 2000;` here you create int variable and initialize it by 2000 , and you can change this value through your code if you want , `int anLeapYear=////but the value here;`,i just try to explain to you how to do it , but you need more learning :)

Comment: "variable year might not have been initialized" on Leap.class on the line public Leap() {} I've commented out //this.isLeapYear; and //this.isNotLeapYear; –